# Why doesn't menu on drop down appear over content?

Tags: css, menu, z-index

I've got a drop down menu that won't appear over the rest of the content. I've set the position to absolute and the z-index to 99 and no luck. Any ideas how to get it to lay on top of the rest of the site?

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">Relaxr</h1>

            <nav>
                <a href='#'><span class="hamburger"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        <div class="container">

nav {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul {
    display: none;
}
header {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
body {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#main {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.hamburger {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 0.74em;
    border-top: 0.2em solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #fff;
}
.hamburger:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.9em;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 0.2em solid #fff;
}
nav ul {    
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 100%;  
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 99;
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/wWvPJm

Comment: Where is the dropdown menu? Are you looking for a way to display the menu items at the top as a dropdown menu instead of in a row?

Comment: Sorry. You have to resize the codepen to make it mobile size. If you click the hamburger menu, the nav opens but behind everything not over the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your @media query change

```
nav {
    position: relative;
}
```

to

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will keep your menu on top.

Comment: Great. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use  something like this to work

```
$(".hamburger").click(function(e){
    $("nav > ul").toggle();
});
```

there is only one difference I've added a closing bracket in

```
$("nav > ul").toggle();
```